# Is there an Angular2 component that allows displaying a big list of items (millions of records) without performance degradation?

Tags: performance, angular

Is there an Angular2 component that allows displaying a huge list of items (millions of records) without performance degradation?

I am not necessarily looking for a grid container, but rather for something that works with *ngFor. I think this kind of component should automatically remove and add items on scroll.

Comment: You are looking for virtual scrolling. I don't know if there is something available already for Angular2.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I found ng2-virtualized, but seems to be more oriented towards tables.

Comment: What else is "big list of items" than a table? (even when it's only a table with a single column)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DataScroller from PrimNG at http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datascroller

Comment: for millions of records,  http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datascroller is not going to help datascroller is not virtual-scrolling it is not removing anything from DOM even if it not visible